# How do I configure Plotly to resize a graph to fit it's background image?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python

I'm using Plotly Dash to display a graph that overlays an image. This image is quite large, being 7490x4906, but will be sized down. The issue I have is it seems like Plotly is restricting the height of the graph which causes the image to display smaller than I need (in some instances, there is nothing on the graph, it's just the image).

Because my webpage will be used on any number of devices, I need `autosize` to be true and cannot statically set the size of the image. Is there any way Plotly can size the graph based on the image? Or, more specifically, resize the graph to fit the image's width while maintaining the aspect ratio of the image?

Here is what I am currently using:

```py
# Load the image
image = cv2.imread("image.png")

# Initialize figure
figure = go.Figure(
    layout=go.Layout(
        autosize=True,
        font={"color": "black", "family": "Arial"},
        margin={"t": 40, "b": 10, "r": 5, "l": 10},
        paper_bgcolor="#ffffff",
        plot_bgcolor="#ffffff",
        xaxis={
            "showgrid": False,
            "tickfont": {"color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"},
            "visible": False,
        },
        yaxis={
            "showgrid": False,
            "tickfont": {"color": "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)"},
            "visible": False,
        },
    ),
)

# Encode the image for Plotly
_, buffer = cv2.imencode(".png", image)
encoded_image = base64.b64encode(buffer)

# Populate the figure
figure.add_layout_image(
    go.layout.Image(
        source="data:image/png;base64,{image}".format(image=encoded_image.decode()),
        xref="paper",
        yref="paper",
        x=0.5,
        y=0.5,
        sizex=1,
        sizey=1,
        xanchor="center",
        yanchor="middle",
    ),
)

# Disable zoom
figure.update_xaxes(fixedrange=True)
figure.update_yaxes(fixedrange=True)
```

EDIT:

A screenshot of what the above code produces:
[image]

Changing `sizey` to `3` in the `go.layout.Image` configuration results in this:
[image]

Ideally, I would like something like the second image; however, with there being no cut off. My application wraps the graph in a bootstrap card. However, I've already attempted to increase the height of the card with no change in the result. The graph doesn't get any taller to fit the picture.

EDIT 2:
Here is more code relating to how I wrap and display the figure. This uses `django-plotly-dash`:

```py
from django_plotly_dash import DjangoDash

# Load the image
img = cv2.imread("image.png")

def build_figure(image):
   # Put the code from what I am currently using here and return figure
   ...

app = DjangoDash("circuits", suppress_callback_exceptions=True)
app.layout = html.Div(
    children=[
        dbc.Card(
            dbc.CardBody(
                dcc.Graph(
                    config={"displaylogo": False},
                    figure=build_figure(img),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ],
)
```

Comment: Could you add a working (or non-working) full example and maybe a screenshot showing the issue? Currently, that seems to add the figure and the layout - is that all you need?

Comment: @Filipe I provided the screenshots as requested. I can't provide a full example though. This graph is generated and managed through ``django-plotly-dash`` and trying to write an MRE wouldn't be worth it. I'm hoping the code I provide will be enough for someone to have a starting point. Also, any large picture will work.

Comment: "worth it" is a bad choice of words; I mean to say not possible for how much work it would be. Apologies.

Comment: So, do you want to change the proportions of the original image? Because the `sizex` and `sizey` configures the container size relative to the plot width (since you used `paper` as reference). If you want to fill the space, without cutting, you should keep `sizex=1` and `sizey=1`. You can use the `sizing` argument to stretch the image. See more about it [here](https://plotly.com/python/reference/layout/images/).

Comment: Setting ``sizing`` to ``fill`` turned the graph into the second image; however, it is still getting cut off on the top and bottom. Using ``stretch`` as you've noted stretched the image out which I can't use. It has definitely got me closer, so thank you. Let me peruse the documentation of ``django-plotly-dash`` to see if I can find anything that might also be there which could help. Also, do you believe ``paper`` is the correct reference?

Comment: I don't see another option: you either fit the figure vertically and get white space on the sides, fit it horizontally and cut it above and below, or stretch it. Could you add a "mockup" figure of what is the desired goal?